# OTF version of DejaVu fonts

Tags: fonts

I have a requirement to use the DejaVu fonts with an application that only supports OTF format fonts.  I've tried the free online font converters like www.freefontconverter.com/ and https://onlinefontconverter.com and while they come back with an OTF file, it does not seem valid.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Out of curiosity: which application is it that only supports OTF and not TTF?

Comment: It is an internally develop application.  So nothing you have to worry about biting you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update: 
We ended up using the font tools from [FontGear](http://www.fontgear.net/), but I also got this excellent reply from Jim Cloos on the DejaVu mailing list that details how to use FontForge to do the conversion:

> I'd suggest building OTF (aka SFNT/CFF) versions of the faces in
>   fontforge directly from the sfd files.
>
> It should be scriptable, but in the GUI choose Element -> Font Info
>   and, in that dialog, Layers.  There, click on All Layers Cubic. 
>   Optionally, within that same dialog, go to General and set the Em size
>   to 1000.
>
> I'd suggest doing Edit -> Select -> Select All and Element -> Correct
>   Direction, as well as Element -> Simplify and Element -> Round.
>
> If you want CFF hints, with Edit -> Select -> Select All do Hints ->
>   AutoHint.
>
> You can then use File -> Generate Fonts and specify OpenType(CFF).
>
> In the Generate dialog, the Options button pulls up another dialog
>   where you can tweak the generation.